# invalid public key - revolut sandbox

Tags: api, ssl, openssl, x509, public-key

Not a developer but trying to figure things out to generate a revolut business api to set up a sandbox revolut payment gateaway on woocommerce. I followed open ssl [instructions](https://revolut-engineering.github.io/api-docs/business-api/#authentication-setting-up-access-to-your-business-account) to generate a X509 certificate, i extract the public key from a .cer file, copy paste it to [revolut business api page](https://sandbox-business.revolut.com/settings/api), but it tells me it's invalid. Does any one have an idea here? there was the same question on a revolut forum 5 months ago but unanswered. THANKS for the help!

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: May be you need to include being and end footers of public key

Comment: waow you're my saver, thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 1):

the answer is to put the being and end footers of public key.
Thank you confused genius

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

MIZTREPH3LURhnx........bQ==

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try and revive this post.
Going through the same process at the moment. I've created certificates using script provided on Revolut documentation, I've ran them using CMD:

```
openssl genrsa -out privatecert.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key privatecert.pem -out publiccert.cer -days 1825
```

I have then ran following script to retrive the key:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in publiccert.cer
```

Which spits out the key in next few lines & to be fair it looks like it's already in the right format:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

MIIBIjA.....

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

However, after pasting it in I also get invlaid public key. Am I doing something wrong here?
[image]